# how to login using apollo mutation Graphql login api?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, rect

```
 const LoginQuery = gql`
  mutation {
    login(data: {
      email: "cherineewong@gmail.com",
      password: "Imagine100!"
  
    })
  } 
`;
```

This is my graphql login api mutation code I don't get any response.
geting error like this `Invariant Violation: Running a Query requires a graphql Query, but a Mutation was used instead.`
I'm also use query keyword like this,

```
  const LoginQuery = gql`
  query mutation {
    login(data: {
      email: "cherineewong@gmail.com",
      password: "Imagine100!"
  
    })
  } 
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LoginQuery);
console.log(data)
```

then getting error this as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2NAw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use apollo's `useMutation` hook

`import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client"`

```
export const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String) {
       login(input: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
          message // ... the keys which you expecting in response from the server.
         
       }   
    } 
`
```

`const [submitLogin] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION);`

Then you can use the handle login method like this

```
const response = await submitLogin({ variables:
  { 
    email: "cherineewong@gmail.com",
    password:  "Imagine100!"
  }
});
console.log('response -- ', response);
```

**For Reference** https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation

Comment: Password is also a must so

`export const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql
    mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
       login(input: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
          message // ... the keys which you expecting in response from the server.
         
       }   
    } 
`
Adding ! for password too will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For mutations, you should apollo's `useMutation` hook

ref: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation